# Twitter Share buttons Stopped Working

Tags: twitter

I have 2 sites where the Twitter Share buttons stopped working.

Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Here are links to my sites:

- http://bit.ly/PMVJeA
- http://bit.ly/MQQdYG

Problem seems isolated to IE8, not sure about Chrome...seems okay in FF14

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're having issues at the moment that the new or old twitter version of the "Twitter Share Button" with any version of IE is causing *some* of the JavaScript on our sites to not execute. (Specifically header related)

After tinkering for an hour or so, I've shelved it. Just used IE browser detection to stop it from putting the Twitter button on IE browsers.

Sorry I can't be of more help - but I get the feeling that this is at Twitters end.